# Sharepoint Online (O365) - Only search Document Title and Names

Tags: search, office-365, document, crawl

If i search for a document name in the Document Library, it returns a list of files that contain the search word, but not the document with the correct title.

I want to change the search in Sharepoint so that only document titles and names are searched.

I already found the managed properties -> Contents and the field "mappings to crawled properties" (i hope i translated it correct)

[image: crawled properties]

Now someone here mentioned too look out for "Basic:10(Text)"
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/562c3f58-aa64-40a9-8661-a4543da99ef4/search-file-names-in-document-libraries?forum=sharepointsearchprevious

I only need search to find document titles

What do i need to change here without breaking everything?

I hope you can help me a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to search the title then specify that in your query:

```
title:"search tips"
```

For more about search syntax see [Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)

Comment: tell that my users. This is really not possible to communicate. Or is there the possibility to adjust search that is puts the Title or File Name statement as default?